# woocommerce - billing order fields change with different countries

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming, woocommerce

I'm working with woocommerce to build a webshop. I've customized the order of the billing address fields. The problem is, some countries still display a different order. How can I force the custom order for all countries?

EDIT:

```
<?php
/*
 * Modifing the order of form fields.
 * More information here: http://www.trottyzone.com/change-order-of-woocommerce-fields-on-checkout-page/
 */
add_filter('woocommerce_checkout_fields','reorder_woo_fields');

function reorder_woo_fields($fields) {
    //move these around in the order you'd like
    $fields2['billing']['billing_first_name'] = $fields['billing']['billing_first_name'];
    $fields2['billing']['billing_last_name'] = $fields['billing']['billing_last_name'];
    $fields2['billing']['billing_email'] = $fields['billing']['billing_email'];
    $fields2['billing']['billing_company'] = $fields['billing']['billing_company'];
    $fields2['billing']['billing_address_1'] = $fields['billing']['billing_address_1'];
    $fields2['billing']['billing_postcode'] = $fields['billing']['billing_postcode'];
    $fields2['billing']['billing_city'] = $fields['billing']['billing_city'];
    $fields2['billing']['billing_country'] = $fields['billing']['billing_country'];
    $fields2['billing']['billing_state'] = $fields['billing']['billing_state'];
    $fields2['billing']['billing_phone'] = $fields['billing']['billing_phone'];

    $fields2['shipping']['shipping_first_name'] = $fields['shipping']['shipping_first_name'];
    $fields2['shipping']['shipping_last_name'] = $fields['shipping']['shipping_last_name'];
    $fields2['shipping']['shipping_email'] = $fields['shipping']['shipping_email'];
    $fields2['shipping']['shipping_company'] = $fields['shipping']['shipping_company'];
    $fields2['shipping']['shipping_address_1'] = $fields['shipping']['shipping_address_1'];
    $fields2['shipping']['shipping_postcode'] = $fields['shipping']['shipping_postcode'];
    $fields2['shipping']['shipping_city'] = $fields['shipping']['shipping_city'];
    $fields2['shipping']['shipping_country'] = $fields['shipping']['shipping_country'];
    $fields2['shipping']['shipping_state'] = $fields['shipping']['shipping_state'];
    $fields2['shipping']['shipping_phone'] = $fields['shipping']['shipping_phone'];

    //just copying these keeps the standard order
    $fields2['account'] = $fields['account'];
    $fields2['order'] = $fields['order'];

    return $fields2;
}

?>
```

Answer (score 2):

Check the woocommerce class-wc-countries.php file there it sets the locale. I think your problem can solved by the following code

`add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_country_locale', 'use_only_default_locale' );
function use_only_default_locale( $locale ) {
  return array();
}`

EDIT:

Try this code

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_default_address_fields', 'my_default_address_fields' );
function my_default_address_fields( $fields ) {
  //move these around in the order you'd like
  $fields2['first_name'] = $fields['first_name'];
  $fields2['last_name'] = $fields['last_name'];
  $fields2['email'] = $fields['email'];
  $fields2['company'] = $fields['company'];
  $fields2['address_1'] = $fields['address_1'];
  $fields2['postcode'] = $fields['postcode'];
  $fields2['city'] = $fields['city'];
  $fields2['city']['label'] = 'City';
  $fields2['city']['placeholder'] = 'City';
  $fields2['country'] = $fields['country'];
  $fields2['state'] = $fields['state'];
  $fields2['phone'] = $fields['phone'];

  return $fields2;
}
```

comment out `add_filter('woocommerce_checkout_fields','reorder_woo_fields');`
You need to change the field classes a bit to fill properly.

Comment: It works to some extent. But now i'm not able to control the format of the locale fields. A simple example: the placeholder for city is 'Town/City', while I want it to be just 'city'. And the postcode is completely gone.

Comment: In class-wc-countries.php line no 725 you will find the default address field you can change it using filter `woocommerce_default_address_fields` in order to change Town/City to city you can use 
`add_filter( 'woocommerce_default_address_fields', 'my_default_address_fields' );
function my_default_address_fields( $fields ) {
  $fields['city']['label'] = 'City';
  $fields['city']['placeholder'] = 'City';
}`

Comment: It turns my country field in a normal one instead of a select.

Comment: Oops i missed the return statement code should be `add_filter( 'woocommerce_default_address_fields', 'my_default_address_fields' );
function my_default_address_fields( $fields ) {
 $fields['city']['label']       = 'City';
 $fields['city']['placeholder'] = 'City';
 return $fields;
}`
can you send me your checkout customization code. It would help me find a better solution

Comment: I've added the code I use to reorder checkout elements

Answer (score 0):

By using the `woocommerce_checkout_fields` filter you have full controll of the checkout fields.

```
// Hook in
add_filter( 'woocommerce_checkout_fields' , 'custom_override_checkout_fields' );

// Our hooked in function - $fields is passed via the filter!
function custom_override_checkout_fields( $fields ) {
    //Minipulate the `$fields` vaiable and return it
    $fields['order']['order_comments']['placeholder'] = 'My new placeholder';
    return $fields;
}
```

See the docs for more information: http://docs.woothemes.com/document/tutorial-customising-checkout-fields-using-actions-and-filters

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Im already using this filter. But this filter is for changing the format of the form, rather than the order in which the fields appear. I'm using the 'reorder_woo_fields' filter to change the default order of the fields. But i'm still getting a different order at some countries.